# How to change file name and extension in Python?

Tags: python

I want to move and rename file called `malicious.txt` located at path `/home/dina/A` to a new location `/home/dina/b` with a new name based on `apkName` (e.g. `a.apk` or `b.apk`, etc) I want the final name to have `.json` extension instead of `.apk` extension - e.g `a.json` and `b.json`

I tried :

```
import os
os.rename("malicious.txt",apkName)
```

But it removes `malicious.txt` without appear any other files.

Comment: It's much more better if you could write some examples of files (e.g. my/path/file1.txt [enter] my/path/file2.txt) for before and after running a script. Then people can see clearly what you want to do and what's wrong with your script.

Answer (score 0):

The following should rename "malicious.txt" to be name of apkfile with extension of ".json"

```
import os
apkName = "a.apk"
apkFullpath = os.path.join(os.path.sep,"home","dina","a",apkName)
jsonName = os.path.splitext(apkName)[0]+".json"
jsonFullpath = os.path.join(os.path.sep,"home","dina","b",jsonName)
os.rename("malicious.txt",jsonName)
```

Note that you can rename file name only once (after the first time of rename, you won't be able to access the old name)

for more info about **os.path.join** and **os.path.sep**

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

**os.path.join(path, *paths)**

Join one or more path components intelligently. The return value is the concatenation of path and any members of *paths with exactly one directory separator (os.sep) following each non-empty part except the last, meaning that the result will only end in a separator if the last part is empty. If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

On Windows, the drive letter is not reset when an absolute path component (e.g., r'\foo') is encountered. If a component contains a drive letter, all previous components are thrown away and the drive letter is reset. Note that since there is a current directory for each drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.

Comment: apkname already called a.apk I want to change malicious.txt to a.json so I don't know how can I write apkname that called (a) only without its extension  and then add (.json)as new extension

Comment: @dina - see my updated answer. jsonName takes the first part of apkName ("a") and adds the ".json" extension - so "a.apk" turns to be "a.json"